# Passing PDF variables to MySQL database

Tags: javascript, mysql

I must configure a PDF form so that it can send variables to a MySQL database upon the press of a button. Knowing that PDF works with javascript, this is the script I made to fetch a variable value for the button press in the PDF.

```
function transfert(){
    var name = (this.getField("Name").value) ;
        window.location.href = "http://something/execute.php?var1="+name;
}
```

From what I understand, this is suppose to send variables to the FTP that I have. What I am not sure of is the next step which is connecting this URL with the MySQL database that was given to me so I can store the data from the PDF. I know I have to use $get but I dont understand how to connect the URL and the database so that MySQL knows where to get from.
Thank you

Comment: `window` isn't a part of the Javascript language, it's part of the DOM. I don't think there is a DOM in the Acrobat JS API. I have never written Javascript for a PDF but I'd be suprised if you could make any kind of network connection at all from a PDF, that sounds like a security issue. I don't think what you're trying to do is possible.

Comment: Could there be another way to pass variables from local pdf javascript --> URL --> MySQL?

Comment: Does it have to be a *pdf* form?

Comment: Sadly yes but i would much rather have an html form